# Переключение overflow-y у модального окна и body

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Есть модальное окно, которое выезжает сверху. При этом необходимо, чтобы `overflow-y` был `scroll`, а также чтобы на странице всегда была 1 полоса прокрутки. Проблема заключается в том, что открытие данного модального окна идет с `transition: .25s`, из-за этого при открытии модального окна скролл модального окна открывается раньше, чем убирается скролл `body`, в следствие этого рядом со скроллом body появляется еще 1 скролл модального окна, а при закрытии модального окна его скролл убирается раньше, чем появляется скролл `body`.

Т.е. пользователь нажимает на кнопку, открывается модальное окно, скролл модального окна уже открыт, а скролл `body` еще не закрыт.

Наоборот происходит при закрытии модального окна - скролл модального окна убирается, а скролл body не добавляется.

Кто знает, как это пофиксить?

Код:

```
<body>
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="popup_item popup_slide"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
var popup = $('.popup');
    $('.popup_open').click(function(){
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        popup.show();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').css('overflowY', 'hidden');
            $(link).addClass('popup_slide-active');
        }, 10);
    });
    $('.close_popups').click(function(){        
        $('.popup_slide').removeClass('popup_slide-active');    
        $('body').css('overflowY', 'auto');
        setTimeout(function(){
           popup.hide();
        }, 500);
    });
```

P.S. нужно так же, как сделано на http://www.transitplus.ru/ скролл модального окна появляется под скроллом body

Comment: может проблема в таймаутах?

Comment: @Horchynskyi нет, в таймаутах не может быть проблем. Таймауты сделаны только для своеобразного коллбэка, т.е. `popup.show()` срабатывает -> запускается функция. `div.popup` имеет `display: none` и таймауты сделаны, чтобы добавлялся класс только после изменения `display: block`